# Is it possible to see iPhone screen from XCode or AppCode debugger?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, appcode

I have MacBook, iPhone and cable. I have connected them. On Android I am able to run my application on connected device and see it's screen from desktop computer. Is the same possible from within MacBook?

Comment: You can mirror the iphone's screen onto your desktop via quicktime. I usually only use this if I need to screenshare or something, not for active development (not sure if thats what you are looking for). Simulators from Xcode are much faster and closer to the real thing, than Android studio emulators, so I have less of a need to constantly use a real device

Comment: If the purpose is to analyze iPhone screen as a "still" image, you can use the View Debugger. Similarly you can ask Xcode to take a screenshot of the device. If the purpose is to see the iPhone screen live while the app is running, I would suggest looking at the iPhone screen. :)

Comment: @matt looking by human eyes is impossible :D

Comment: That's a good answer! :))) In that case the QuickTime solution is probably best, though you won't be able to tap or anything like that.